# The ThemeData useMaterial3 isnt working in others routes or class

Tags: flutter, dart, material-design

As i describe in the title my have 2 route or classes a loginscreen and a homepage, the problem is that the `useMaterial3` is only working on the loginscreen and isn't work on the homepage

This is the `main.dart`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tesis/home.dart';
import 'package:tesis/login.dart';
import 'package:tesis/theme/color_schemes.g.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Tesis',
      theme: ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        colorScheme: lightColorScheme,
      ),
      darkTheme: ThemeData(colorScheme: darkColorScheme),
      initialRoute: '/',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const LoginScreen(),
        '/second': (context) => const Home(),
      },
      // home: const LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the loginscreen

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tesis/home.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LoginScreen> createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  bool _visibility = true;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/background.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 447,
            clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
            ),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Text(
                  'Bienvenido',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontSize: 36,
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0)),
                const Text(
                  'Ingresar',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                    fontSize: 24,
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 250,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Usuario',
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(7.0),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 250,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    obscureText: _visibility,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                        prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock),
                        labelText: 'Contraseña',
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(
                              _visibility
                                  ? Icons.visibility
                                  : Icons.visibility_off,
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _visibility = !_visibility;
                              });
                            })),
                  ),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(11.0),
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    // Foreground color
                    onPrimary: Colors.white,
                    // Background color
                    primary: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                  ).copyWith(
                    elevation: ButtonStyleButton.allOrNull(0.0),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/second');
                  },
                  child: const Text('Iniciar Sección'),
                ),
                const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(11.0),
                ),
                Text.rich(
                  TextSpan(
                      text: 'Aún no te has registrado?',
                      children: <TextSpan>[
                        TextSpan(
                          text: ' Registrate',
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                            fontSize: 14,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the homepage

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tesis/login.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
          },
        ),
        title: Text('Title Large'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: (() {}),
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve this, i just forget to put the `useMaterial3: true,` inside the `darkTheme: ThemeData(colorScheme: darkColorScheme),`